# Increment Nested Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, increment

I hope my question isn't answered elsewhere. I have a question about incrementing the value in a nested dictionary. Here is the relevant section of code.

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("sample.xlsx")
rsheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

uniquenames = ["Smith", "Jones", "Mark"]
varlist = ["x", "y", "z"]
var = {}
for x in varlist:
    var[x] = 0
for g in uniquenames:
    namerows[g] = var
p = 1
while p<(rsheet.nrows):
    name = rsheet.cell_value(p, 5)
    n = 11
    if name in uniquenames:
        for varb in varlist:
            namerows[name][varb] += rsheet.cell_value(p,n)
            n+=1
    p+=1
```

The problem I have is that Python is returning the anticipated values for the Excel cells, (rsheet.cell_value(p,n)) and the anticipated values for the nested dictionary values (namerows[name][varb]), but appears to be incrementing the nested dictionary values double the amount intended. Is this issue related to the amount of dictionaries I have?

```
print namerows["Smith"]["x"], p, rsheet.cell_value(p, 12)
```

Adding the above snippet to the while loop returns (just an example portion of the output):

```
726 13861 0.0
726 13862 1.0
728 13863 0.0
```

I'm sure this is my own flawed understanding of Python that is the problem, but any insight would be appreciated. My eventual goal with this code is to come up with total sums for each variable for each name (many repeats of each name), similar to the way pivot tables do group sums/averages etc. in Excel. Thanks in advance. (python 2.7, xlrd 0.9.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly valid to have a dictionary of dictionaries. Your problem is in this line:

```
for g in uniquenames:
    namerows[g] = var
```

For each name, you are setting the value of `namerows[name]` to the *same* dictionary object `var`.

So `namerows["Smith"]` is just another reference to the same dictionary as `namerows["Jones"]`. If you run `namerows["Smith"]["x"] += 1`, you will see that you have also incremented `namerows["Jones"]["x"]`. Try it!

What you need to do is to make a copy of the dictionary `var` for each key in namerows:

```
for g in uniquenames:
    namerows[g] = var.copy()
```

CAVEAT: Now one thing to be careful of with nested dictionaries is if you want to make a copy of `namerows`, using `namerows.copy()`, the inner dictionaries will be the same objects in both copies. This is called a *shallow copy*. To make a *deep copy*, where the inner dictionaries are also copies, you need to `import copy` and run `new_namerows = copy.deepcopy(namerows)`. See the [copy module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for more information.

Comment: thats it exactly. everything works seamlessly! thanks for the quick, well-thought-out answer. didnt realize that i had to explicitly make it a copy, thats what i thought i was essentially doing.